# Resume screen in libGDX, instead of create new instance

Tags: java, libgdx

Is it possible in libGDX to resume screen A after hitting a back button in screen B without creating new instance of screen A? This way the my player character just resume walking from its last location instead of walking from a starting point. 
When user navigate to screen B from screen A, screen A is paused, but the game is not.

I usually use the following code in class ScreenB to switch between screens:

```
btnLabsEnter.addListener(new InputListener(){
                 @Override
                    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                      getGame().setScreen(new ScreenA(getGame()));
                          return true;
                 }
             });
```

The code above, however, is for creating new instance of Screen A instead of showing previously hidden Screen A.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "right" way to do this. For example, if your screens don't require a large number of resources then you can create them up front in your *Game* class and just switch between them without creating new instances.

That's what I did for [Very Angry Robots](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos/very-angry-robots/very-angry-robots/src/com/badlydrawngames), and the game ran perfectly well on low-end phones two years ago. I wouldn't do it this way each time, but for a resource-light game it works perfectly well.

```
/** Creates all the screens that the game will need, then switches to the main menu. */
@Override
public void create () {
    Assets.load();
    mainMenuScreen = new MainMenuScreen(this);
    playingScreen = new WorldPresenter(this);
    scoresScreen = new ScoresScreen(this);
    setScreen(mainMenuScreen);
}
```

Comment: One question with this. How do you go about preventing the Game class calling the show() method on the screen it switches to? At the moment if I do the above and use setScreen(), whilst it doesn't create a new instance of the screen, it still calls show, which essentially creates all new content. Is it just a case of creating a homegrown version of setScreen / checking the state in show()? Or is there a clever way of doing it I missed?